# C++ Sorting Function

Tags: c++, oop, sorting

So I'm trying to get a sort function to work. It should sort by firstname, but if the first names are the same it should sort by last names. I keep getting an error in `mySort()` that says "unexpected primary-expression before ')' token" on line where `inOrder = arr`. What's happening to this and how can I fix it? I need to pass my objects into a function in a seperate class. I'll link them in pastebin.

Here's the driver

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "phoneEntry.h"
using namespace std;

void mySort(PhoneEntry& arr, int size)
{
    bool inOrder = false;
    for (int i = size - 1; i > 0 && !inOrder; i--)
    {
        inOrder = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            inOrder = arr.alphaGreater(arr&);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{   
    const int MAXNUM = 500;
    PhoneEntry entry[MAXNUM];
    ifstream filezilla;
    filezilla.open("phone.txt");
    int count = 0;

    if(filezilla)
    {
        while(count < MAXNUM && entry[count].readEntry(filezilla))
        {
            count++;
        }
        mySort(entry&, count);
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            entry[i].writeEntry(cout) << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Four Oh Four - File Not Found" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Phone Entry Header](http://pastebin.com/f6Xvu398)

[Phone Number Header](http://pastebin.com/ytdi8x3D)

Sorting Text (http://pastebin.com/HE8Rsmbg)

Comment: Is this for learning purposes? If not and you need it for work/hobby, I recommend one of the dedicated standard sorting algorithms, which have different targets like "full sort", "top XXX, sorted", "top XXX, unsorted", "only nth element, rest remains unsorted", etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to pass a reference, so the argument has to be defined as call-by-reference in the function definition/declaration, which is already done:

```
bool PhoneEntry::alphaGreater(const PhoneEntry& item) const;
```

As you can see, `PhoneEntry::alphaGreater` takes a constant `PhoneEntry` *reference*. So simply use

```
inOrder = arr.alphaGreater(arr);
```

Comment: Do all objects pass as reference? I keep running into initialization errors in my main when I try to pass my object as reference. Also thanks for the help, will accept answer in 3 min when it lets me!

Comment: @JohnSmith: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29. Objects will only pass as a reference if used in a call-by-reference function.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the right answer.  I don't know what he's trying to do with `alf&` in this context, and I suspect that he wants to pass the array to `mySort`, and not just a single instance.  (And of course, you can't pass C style arrays to functions, so his array should actually be `std::vector<PhoneEntry>`.  Otherwise, he's stuck with awkward hacks involving implicit conversion to pointer and such.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Technically it's the right answer to "What's happening to this [`unexpected primary-expression before ')' token"`] and how can I fix it?", however I didn't really pay attention to the rest of the program. This will not fix his program entirely, as there are several other things wrong with his code. +1 on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your code.  The first, the one the
compiler is complaining about, is that there is no postfix operator `&`
in C++.  I don't know exactly what you're trying to do with it, or what
you think it means, but it doesn't exist in C++.

The second is that `mySort` takes a reference to a single `PhoneEntry`;
you have an array of `PhoneEntry`, so you'll have to select one to pass
it.  Except that the name of the function and the fact that you pass a
count as well suggest that you really want to pass an array.

And I can't figure out what `mySort` is supposed to be doing.  It
certainly doesn't sort anything; in fact, it seems to be fundamentally
an expensive no-op, since it doesn't return anything, it doesn't modify
`arr`, and it doesn't access or modify any global state.

For the rest, you need more error checking on the input (did the open
succeed, etc.), and you really should be using `std::vector`, rather
than a C style array.  (There are cases where C style arrays are
appropriate, but this isn't one of them.)

More fundamentally, I'd suggest you get a good book and study it.  (I'd
recommend Stroustrup's *Programming Principles and Practice Using C++*.)
You can't write a program in any language without knowing at least the
most basic fundamentals and basic syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm just following what my homework wants, were going the long way for everything. mySort isn't really doing the sorting, alphaGreater() is doing the sorting but I needed to modify a sort code function that was predefined in my homework (which is a bubble sort) to pass values into alphaGreater() which should sort it alphabetically. I was taught that the `&` operator means "Pass by Reference"

Comment: `alphaGreater` can only act on its arguments: the object on which it is called, and the argument you pass it.  In your code, they are the same thing, so I fail to see how it can change the order of anything.  And depending on context: the `&` binary operator means bitwise and, the `&` prefix operator means take the address of, and there is no `&` suffix operator in C++.  In a declaration (not an expression), a prefixed `&` means reference, but only in a declaration, and it's still a prefix.  And again, I'd really suggest a good book; there's just too much to cover in an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass it as pointers also